# finalPolygonCRS + over() function sp package in R

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial, r-sp

I create a `SpatialPolygon` this way

```
#make spatial points
#assign Original CRS WGS84 EPSG:4326 (DATUM --> on sphere)
cornersEPSG4326 <- SpatialPoints(coords=cbind(x,y), proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))

#transform to EPSG3857 (Web Mercator PROJECTION)
cornersEPSG3857 <- spTransform(cornersEPSG4326, CRS("+init=epsg:3857"))

#create Polygon
bbox <- Polygon(cornersEPSG3857)

#create PolygonsObject
myPolygon <- Polygons(list(bbox),1)

#create SpatialPolygonsObject
finalPolygon <- SpatialPolygons(list(myPolygon))

#say that polygon is EPSG3857 (Web Mercator PROJECTION)
proj4string(finalPolygon) <- CRS("+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs")
```

And `SpatialPoints` this way:

```
#make spatial points
#assign Original CRS WGS84 EPSG:4326 (DATUM --> on sphere)               
spatialEPSG4326 <- SpatialPoints(coords=cbind(x,y), proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))

#transform to EPSG3857 (Web Mercator PROJECTION)
spatialEPSG3857 <- spTransform(spatialEPSG4326, CRS("+init=epsg:3857"))

allPointsSpatial <- spatialEPSG3857
```

I wanto run the `over()` function:

```
pointsInPolygon <- over(allPointsSpatial, finalPolygon)
print(length(pointsInPolygon))
```

But, I recieve the following error message:

> Warning: Unhandled error in observer: identicalCRS(x, y) is not TRUE

When I add this line to my `SpatialPoints`

```
#say that points is EPSG3857 (Web Mercator PROJECTION)
proj4string(spatialEPSG3857) <- CRS("+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs")
```

I get the following error:

> Warning in `proj4string<-`(`*tmp*`, value = ) :   A new CRS was assigned to an object with an existing CRS:
>   +init=epsg:3857 +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs without reprojecting. For reprojection, use function spTransform in
>   package rgdal

1. Why is the `CRS are not identical` error raised? They should be the same since the `proj4string` and the `spTransform` is the same code?!
2. Why is this error raised when I try to assign the `proj4string` to the SpatialPoints, but not when I do it on the Polygon?

Comment: can you add `dput(x)` and `dput(y)` to your question?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not just using `CRS("+init=epsg:4326")`? I can't test whether this works without sample data but it seems it should because it's listed here: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/

Comment: @MichaelChirico using this `CRS("+init=epsg:4326")` instead of which line?!

Comment: anywhere where you are trying to use Mercator, e.g. declaring `cornersEPSG4326`

Comment: @MichaelChirico I thought I need to use the `proj4string` for that?! Checking here http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/ that is would be that one http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/proj4/ ?

Comment: Hmm not sure I follow you, but for example doesn't `cornersEPSG4326 <- SpatialPoints(coords=cbind(x,y), proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))` work?

Comment: and similarly for using `CRS("+init=epsg:3587")`

Comment: @MichaelChirico yep. got confused with the numbers. In the code its correct though. Well if you look here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/sp.pdf it says when you create `SpatialPoints` you need to define the `proj4string=CRS(as.character(NA))`. If you check the `proj4string` here spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326  its what I wrote! Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88731/discussion-between-michaelchirico-and-chrissl).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding CRS in sp seems inconsistent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379537/adding-crs-in-sp-seems-inconsistent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this problem can be solved by being more careful about how you specify your CRS throughout your code.

The following produces no errors for me:

```
#test on the unit square
test.box<-as.matrix(rbind(c(0,0),
                          1:0,
                          c(1,1),
                          0:1,
                          c(0,0)))
#store CRS for clarity
EPSG4326<-CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
EPSG3857<-CRS("+init=epsg:3857")

#re-run code:
cornersEPSG4326 <- 
  SpatialPoints(coords=test.box, proj4string = EPSG4326)
cornersEPSG3857 <- spTransform(cornersEPSG4326, EPSG3857)
bbox <- Polygon(cornersEPSG3857)
myPolygon <- Polygons(list(bbox),1)
finalPolygon <- SpatialPolygons(list(myPolygon))
proj4string(finalPolygon) <- EPSG3857

spatialEPSG4326 <- 
  SpatialPoints(coords=test.box, proj4string = EPSG4326)
spatialEPSG3857 <- spTransform(spatialEPSG4326, EPSG3857)
allPointsSpatial <- spatialEPSG3857

#output: no errors
pointsInPolygon <- over(allPointsSpatial, finalPolygon)
> cat(length(pointsInPolygon))
5
```