# Adding CRS in sp seems inconsistent

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial, r-sp

I want to use the `over()` function from the `sp` package in `R`.

I assigne a `CRS`.

```
#say that polygon is EPSG3857 (Web Mercator PROJECTION)
proj4string(finalPolygon) <- CRS("+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs")
```

and all seems good.

```
str(finalPolygon)
> ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
> .. .. ..@ projargs: chr "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs"
```

Lets check the `CRS` of `allPoints`.

```
str(allPoints)
>..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
> .. .. ..@ projargs: chr "+init=epsg:3857 +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_def"
```

So, when I run the `over()` function now

```
pointsInPolygon <- over(allPoints, finalPolygon))
```

I get the error:

> identicalCRS(x, y) is not TRUE

I think I know what the problem is here, but I do not know how to solve it.

If you look closely, `allPoints` has a few words more - namely `+init=epsg:3857`. I read [here](http://grokbase.com/t/r/r-sig-geo/139hfac2yf/problem-with-extract-raster-package-using-weight-true) that the `sp package` simply compares if the **strings** in the `CRS` slot are identical. Well, they are in the same `CRS` as you can see (the creatin of the Spatial reference is exactly the same), but the strings differ slightly due to the process how I created them.

When I use

```
#say that points is EPSG3857 (Web Mercator PROJECTION)
proj4string(spatialEPSG3857) <- CRS("+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs")
```

on the `allPoints` it throws me this back:

> Warning in `proj4string<-`(`*tmp*`, value = ) :   A new CRS was assigned to an object with an existing CRS:
>   +init=epsg:3857 +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs without reprojecting. For reprojection, use function spTransform in
>   package rgdal

The `over()` function works then, but what I get back does not make sense.

How to tackle this problem?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have created `finalPolygon` by

```
finalPolygon <- SpatialPolygons(list(myPolygon), proj4string = CRS(proj4string(cornersEPSG3857)))
```

as its documentation states that the CRS is set to NA by default. Instead, you set the CRS in the next statement to `CRS("+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs")` which is different from

```
> CRS("+init=epsg:3857")
CRS arguments:
 +init=epsg:3857 +ellps=WGS84 +proj=merc +a=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0
+lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs
```

which is what you used for `cornersEPSG3857`. Although these two strings may represent the same CRS (i.e. have the same semantics), they differ syntactically, and neither `sp` nor the underlying `PROJ.4` library (part of GDAL, interfaced through package `rgdal`) have a function to compare semantics of two syntactically different proj4strings.

The solution to this problem is to define the new CRS once, e.g. by

```
crs3857 =  CRS("+init=epsg:3857")
```

and use that throughout your entire script.

(The warning at the end is BTW there to make sure users don't think they reproject when they merely overwrite a CRS; you *did* overwrite it, and it *did* solve your problem too, but in a not so clean way)

Comment: Yep. Thats it. I thought I can add the whole `("+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs"` as the definition for the `CRS` since its said it needs to be the `proj4string` (which would be that)

Comment: If you use one single `proj4string` consistently throughout your script, it should work fine; my solution is not the only clean one.